# TypeScript: Typing problem with "A extends B"

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-types

[Edit - concluding remark]: It has turned out that the question below was mainly the result of some suboptimal typings and normally you might not have such issues like I had in my program => now with this knowledge, my question does not seem to make too much sense any more (as others have already mentioned below).

---

Please have a look at the following TypeScript code snippet.
As `B extends A` this `c: 8` line is of course allowed.
How do I have to change the types of `function f` to forbid others keys next to `a` and `b`?

```js
type A = { a: number, b: number }

function f<B extends A>(b: B): void {
}

f({
  a: 3,
  b: 4,
  c: 8 // <- This shall cause a compile error
})
```

» [Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnAGigM10JKgF8BYAKGYDMcsBjYASwHssUVgB4AQlAgAPYBCwATAM6wAfAApKUUQEpMANz485yZoxZNWqpMyhpMAZlLWKmACyOmNzpgAcUAPR+UMIAtFAAKgAWPEoKEagANvFQnKg4CtCoyXx4YDzx0CTEfMQmWsxAA)

PS: Of course `function f(b: A) {}` is not what I am looking for. This example here is just simplified, the real world use-case is far more complicated ... it's important that `function f` stays generic.

---

[Edit]: As my simplification above caused some confusion:
Please find here a more complex example, where an anwer to my question above could help (an imaginary UI component API):

Please have a look at the type error in Demo-A. This shall be fixed in Demo-B.

[Demo-A (with type error)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=22&pln=12&pc=26#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigJQgYwXAEwB5lg4BLAOwHMAaKAQ0pAD4BYAKFEigDUBRADYQAthErB0jZlAD0sqJQSTyIsPmBNJACwhwInbtF4A5BAWgYArpQsAzKhAJQAPoquDBrqACMECYSZvSisRHz1vUgoabwFhMQlvAElgPQYfYSJTcwh2DkNwaABhBDUESnFgIhgoCAAPVNtUeCRkFikACjBEFAAuWABKdHa40UrOAp4SsoqJEsoHamrahvECZp62qQBvTigoAnJkMEEGEBMGMX6oqjoJjn3u1v7dh-2oAG0AaSgqKABrCAgBB2WAAXRee3e+3sDA8wF4DEEVggAH5+lAbPZHM56o11rBvmCoKisBAAI5Wcj6YgwFhEqD9CoANwi8ig5UEIEYngQAHcDhA7HDBAikSioHZ8BywMByOUkVAnigodD2R8AHRa4nIUrQZS6OBKhhwS4QVJwVAAWkUyl+ZTgmkShoMb32AF8oe7aPd9vpbHoupt+jABv1shY5AoiFabQADZXIENx36oPmIGj0ERWUi+aC6sTAbS3KCCciAqAJ4OwKAAMigABEU3yXY3GPooEWEMh9bL5ZRFYmoC3yDhtFBtAxWYxBcL4VBmeLXe6oPc7DYcHLylA8DNKss8WsNq0WB08AtyNR+tN1LNgPNFtUWGGoDfyvu6VBXn7zVY4JR3E8RhUCYbl2SUFQHSdHQ9GXe52VjRCkNje4jFfBAbAtFoUB2KEqHIOUkRKTD0XcMI9E4T18g4c9c2IiQIgwXdb33eisM2U9vwOI4TjOC4rigAByNi9EEn1qMeasuP2fDCMENjITdd5YXhRFkQgfoAAZVSgKiPXEqF-QsOAg1aIZpKgfRgD-ACABYACYoAAaiVTYNVk8giIwxJ2RjG0ABVi1QZBtAwwRnAgicGDASBKHoBhUA8rzMKikDZxFSRF3Ur1KIGe4gA)

[Demo-B (without type error)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigJQgYwXAEwB5lg4BLAOwHMAaKAQ0pAD4BYAKFEigDUBRADYQAthErB0jZlAD0sqJQSTyIsPmBNJACwhwInbtF4A5BAWgYArpQsAzKhAJQAPoquDBrqACMECYSZvSisRHz1vUgoabwFhMQlvAElgPQYfYSJTcwh2DkNwaABhBDUESnFgIhgoCAAPVNtUeCRkFikACjBEFAAuWABKdHa40UrOAp4WlBLKB2pq9owAb04oKABtAGkoKigAawgQBDtYAF1+1Y519fsGD2BeBkErCAB+fpt7R2d6xoJmtszlA3lgIABHKzkfTEGAsIFQfoVABuEXkUHKghAjE8CAA7lA7g8ni9oHZ8BiwMByOVnlBuq01jd0RsAHTs4HIUrQZS6OD0hhwBhiVJwVAAWkUyl2ZTgmkSfIM1ygAF9OGr8lxClASmUKhJZvNqrUGuIAbAesh6DAiib-s1LYbyAs4UsoFdbuRkGBBAwQCZhRB+lEqHQmQy+rAirQmfpbHoupb+gARCB2e6CVIEabIarWoosAb9bIWdUTLU8VPph5OHN5qN2s0O1pOl0sN01ABk7qZ212lAORxOUYuUYRfyb7sJaYzj2er36VDsEWTqpBUFXn0o+yUeMoZc1dhsOGp5SgeD1lWNE6aFta+cbt5zrcWLA6TLwc2d-V16n1wBfGB8zyIsdVKP8rzhHtlX0YArDgAcQk8RhUCYbF0SUFRZXlHQ9CVDVOHRcViJI0iyPIijKKoyjyyMMCbFFHMpA9ftyGpZ4SgYj53DCPQD04T9SHoiQ9B-cDyivTiRLgHM3QvCCJA6FiCC9H0-QDMR+gAcik0UtJjTV1gjZBLiZdYqDY8gOIQBjTOVG5p2rTMSQXKAAAYDLMm5gG0L0AGVtBswQCCKe5kAgABBX9yGEfg4EQOB+gARhSuQFCIYioAAQhy3K8tyryVU8+yoB8-zAo8EKwsi6LYvi-B+gAJmatKoAyyV8s6rKmSK8t1jjCw4ETVohhY-qIDghCoAAFkaqAAGp6UtVkLPYwRdNa9qoCSbCtH6YyVsoSzrIY3ZUF3DFTjogADEJeLga6oA6TCoFu0Jwn5NwvjTH5roGHr1X+zUgA)

But as you can see in Demo-B you can now add invalid parameters to the component configuration - which is not very nice ... and that's why I have asked the question above.

[Edit - later] Not an answer to my question above, but at least the following modification of Demo-B should work as desired: [Demo-C](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigJQgYwXAEwB5lg4BLAOwHMAaKAQ0pAD4BYAKFEigDUBRADYQAthErB0jZlAD0sqJQSTyIsPmBNJACwhwInbtF4A5BAWgYArpQsAzKhAJQAPoquDBrqACMECYSZvSisRHz1vUgoabwFhMQlvAElgPQYfYSJTcwh2DkNwaABhBDUESnFgIhgoCAAPVNtUeCRkFikACjBEFAAuWABKdHa40UrOAp4WsBLKB2oiABV2jABvTigoewYPYF4GQSsIAH5+m3tHZ3rGglRFqGOofjqcQ4sl+nOIBwqCdv6KgA3CJyBTlQQgRieBAAdy23x2gj2ByOUDs+CgSGA5HKByg3VanAAvhMuIVYD1kLN5tUVlB1hxNgBtADSUCoUAA1hAQAg7LAALr9abU8gLGCsgV5En5Mk8faCcgEaZU8o0mrXcS3CmtegwIq1Bpa5qU0XilgrDZcnl82AGzVNa28-kwK2bR4dbnOwaGm6oT02l1FAZuh6bACMvuN9KgrPZlCdtv1QvpRKjjoA8iJyFV9ZL6F6kz0zUQmKx2o8AAxQfqRolMwtBgWhx6KCDAuCh4VFLttju9oF6UlGKAlMoVCQljVGx0qvX2mfalVTi1SBmbAjkZBgQQMEAmBhifpRKh0K0Evp8A5K5dqsXVecsWhW-S2PRdSn9AAiCN2ThVD52iwAz9NkFjEsO5I-nYiKpMqlKAfq6ZLqad7mnSNQAGT0lacYco2dopnmLICshqCrPCMG7AqRz9FQdgRF+UBpo8TFnJQnJKDClAQbKdg2Dg2LlFAeDjpU1RkTqKDzpJt5zPeMAWh0Vp4PJ1D9GO6gTsAU6PpwIGjqUWniYpOGMlA+jAFYcAJiEniMKgZagooyjsmUcCaIkuj6LxnDyFAAC0QXBSFoVheFEWRRFkE8CUNipHAKprlaVA5uQBxxRIpzuGEQ4cDKnCqaQhnxXoGlGeU4mZQlKp0qJxkSB065bFuO57geR5QAA5NVehdc+sqbBeyD9M1mypdiGUIPFo2hhuv5IjRED9JWA1zc5wDaFuADK2jTYIBBFDsyAQAAgpp5DCPwcCIHAtbhpG-lEEFUAAITvR9n0faGRJreZmz+ZtO17R4h3HWdF1XTd+D9AATPDznPQFb1fajVq-aSmyvhYcAfq0QxjRZEBWTZUAACyw1AADU+KUgAdBN6WCNViMvUk7mecA-TDQzlBpVN8XsqgXGYvyI4AAYhLlcDi1AHRKJIkuhOEcDeF8PxOOLIbmTKRLa5wQA)

Comment: "How do I have to change the types of function f to forbid others keys next to a and b?" is exactly what you are trying to avoid. It seems like you really need `function f(b: A)`

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner Thanks for your comment. I've edited my description above with a more complex example. Maybe this shows better what I mean.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I think you were right, that the use of generics the way I have used them in Demo-2 above, does not make too much sense. I've updated the description above accordingly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Your use case is pretty complicated. I think you were too deep down in the problem, you just needed to step out and rethink this through :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is by design. TS is structural type language where type compatibility is based on subtypying, in other words every type which has all constraints will pass the rule. In your example type of the value has all fields needed, so 'a' and 'b', therefore everything is ok.

There is no reason you should not allow for such object to be passed, as additional fields inside should not make you a difference. Saying that you extend means saying you are allowed to have more fields in terms of composites like objects.

Additional if you want a subtype, but with exact fields the only type which matches your need will be unfortunately `A`, so the function signature should be `f(a: A)`.

And to be clear even with `f(a: A)` you will be able to pass values with additional fields, only object literals will be validated strictly. Any assigned value with more fields can be used without compiler complain. And the reason I describe already.

Comment: I hoped for something like: `function f<B extends A & { [k: string]: never }>(b: B): void {
}`, see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=2&pln=3&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnAGigM10JKgF8BYAKGYDMcsBjYASwHssUVgB4AQlAgAPYBCwATAM6woAMmRQA2gGtMC4MR5YA5gF0qEAG606APgAUlKKICUmC3x5zkzRiyas7JGYoNEwAZlJgikwAFkimEM5MAA4oAHo0qGEAWigAFQALHiUFAtQAG3KoTlQcBWhUar48MB5y6BJiPmIfZ2YgA

Comment: what you are trying to do does not really make sense to me @Natasha if you don't want any other property, why not just use `f(b: A)`? What's the point of having generics?

Comment: @Maciej Many thanks for your responses. Please find in the description above a more complex example, hopefully that shows what I mean.

Comment: @MaciejSikora Maybe you are right that the whole issue was about some misused generics - I've updated the description on top accordingly. Thanks for your help.